# GruntJS Concat don't work (Maximum call stack size exceeded)

Tags: powershell, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

Has anyone faced this error with Concat (Loop Infinite)?
http://pastebin.com/XQsYuqdc

GruntJs on windows
Terminal: PowerShell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are defining a task which will run itself, entering an infinite loop.

This is the problem line:

```js
grunt.registerTask( 'concat', [ 'concat' ] );
```

This will also be a problem:

```js
grunt.registerTask( 'copy', [ 'copy' ] );
```

In both of those cases, there's no reason to define custom tasks to run the grunt tasks (I suggest removing those two lines, and then things will work).

You could define a custom task to run both of those tasks though, something like:

```js
grunt.registerTask( 'build', [ 'concat', 'copy' ] );
```